# Dealing with special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to make a simple form to edit database contents, so I have a php page that has the form and inserts the current database field information into different form fields.

The problem is the database entries have a number of special characters like `&micro;` or `&reg;` and when inserted into the form they display as the special character instead of the code, which, when I insert back into the database can display improperly in a browser.

Does anyone know how I can pull the full code into the form without it converting to the special character?

Comment: if your wanting a stylized rich text form you should ckeditor ot timymce.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before sending input to the database and use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when fetching data from the database and **before** output it into the form.

Form -> htmlspecialchars() -> DB

DB -> htmlentities() -> Form

Comment: No. That will double encode the characters that htmlspecialchars encodes

Comment: Okay, so I tried using htmlspecialchars() on the DB info as I dropped it into the form textarea and it seems to be working perfectly. All of the greater than/equal, less than/equal, degree, micro etc symbols are keeping their original code (ie &micro;) but all the gt, lt, quotes, etc symbols are not being converted. From reading about the function it's working differently than I would expect but I like it! Thanks for the help!